# Hibernate-search: Base class fields are not registered in elastic-search by registering the fields programmatically in hibernate-search

Tags: java, hibernate, elasticsearch, hibernate-search, elasticsearch-5

I have certain fields declared in base class and I want to register those fields for certain sub classes only (entities).

So that I don't want to annotate those fields in base class by @Field and though just registering programmatically for certain entities is enough.

But fields declared in the base entity are not registered/mapped to elastic-search and if try to search then it throws below exception.

I have also tried by moving those field to entities itself instead of declaring it in the base class and registering those fields programmatically works for me, so only if the fields are in base class doesn't work.

Here is my sample code

```
public class BaseEntity{

@Column(name = "created_timestamp")
private String createdTimeStamp;

@Column(name = "created_by")
private ZonedDateTime createdBy;

//getter and setter

}
```

```
@Entity
@Indexed    
public class BookEntity extends BaseEntity{

//other fields
}
```

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class PaperBookEntity extends BaseEntity{

//other fields
}
```

```
public class HibernateSearchFieldMappingService{

@Autowired
private SearchMapping searchMapping;

 @Override
  public <T extends BaseEntity> void registerAuditFields(Class<T> entityClass) {
    LOG.info("Registering audit fields (createdTimeStamp and createdBy) of entity {}", entityClass);
    IndexedMapping indexedMapping = searchMapping.entity(entityClass).indexed();
    FieldMapping fieldMapping = indexedMapping.property("createdTimeStamp", ElementType.FIELD).field();
    fieldMapping.dateBridge(Resolution.SECOND);
    fieldMapping.sortableField();
    indexedMapping.entity(entityClass).indexed().property("createdBy", ElementType.FIELD).field().normalizer("lowercase");
  }

  }
```

Here is my stack trace

```
org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: Unable to find field createdBy in com.*.*.*.BookEntity
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.objectToString(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:1052)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.FieldContext.objectToString(FieldContext.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.buildSearchTerm(ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.createQuery(ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.impl.ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.createQuery(ConnectedMultiFieldsTermQueryBuilder.java:72)
```

Hibernate versions that I use are,

> hibernate-search-elasticsearch, hibernate-search-orm = 5.11.4.Final

Answer (score 1):

The programmatic API in Hibernate Search 5 does not recognize "inherited" properties, only properties declared directly on the type you're mapping. See [HSEARCH-1108](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1108).

The problem has been solved in Hibernate Search 6, so you could solve it by upgrading. Be aware that Hibernate Search 6 is in Beta and APIs are quite different. See [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/) for a getting started guide.

To make this work in Hibernate Search 5 without upgrading to 6, the usual solution is not to use the programmatic API, but to override getters in classes where you want the fields to appear, and annotate the overridden getters.

For example:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity{

@Column(name = "created_by")
private String createdBy;

@Column(name = "created_timestamp")
private ZonedDateTime createdTimeStamp;

public String getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}

public String getCreatedTimeStamp() {
    return createdTimeStamp;
}
}
```

```
@Entity
@Indexed    
public class BookEntity extends BaseEntity{

@Override
@Field(normalizer = @Normalizer(definition = "lowercase"))
public String getCreatedBy() {
    return super.getCreatedBy();
}

@Override
@Field
@SortableField
public String getCreatedTimeStamp() {
    return createdTimeStamp;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess this is the time to upgrade to 6. But what is the release plan of hibernate-serach 6?

Comment: Betas are released approximately every month, hard to say when it will be ready exactly. The main problem you can expect is changes in APIs: the code is already well tested and all the main features are there. So it's suitable for a production environment *if* you're fine with breaking changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column(name = "created_timestamp")
private String createdBy;

@Column(name = "created_by")
private ZonedDateTime createdTimeStamp;
```

Shouldn't it be

```
@Column(name = "created_timestamp")
private String createdTimeStamp;;

@Column(name = "created_by")
private ZonedDateTime createdBy
```

Another assumption **Column name is *created_by* instead *createdBy*

Comment: Aah thats my oversight while copying the code. I edited the description.